# How to inject a javascript file in a Non-Local web page and invoke it

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET 2008. I am building an application which had a webbrowser named "browser1". When I navigate a URL on it like "http://www.google.com" (not "file:///c:/test.html") it successfully loads the page. I am using the code to inject a javascript file in this page.

```
Dim mScript As HtmlElement
Dim mHead As HtmlElement
Dim jsPath As String
jsPath = (SoftwareROOT.Replace("\", "/")) & "/plugin.js"

   With Browser1
       mHead = Browser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
       mScript = .Document.CreateElement("script")
       mScript.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
       mScript.SetAttribute("src", jsPath)
       mHead.AppendChild(mScript)
       .Document.InvokeScript("plugin_main")
   End With
```

The code successfully creates the new element. But when it is trying to invoke script (the 2nd last line) then it fails to run the script.

Note:

1. File path is OK.
2. Code successfully works with a local page (like "c:\test.html").
3. "plugin_main" is a simple function of javascript alert().

Answer (score 0):

You could run the script simply by navigating to it.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:code")
```